# Gnucash ghost entries: missing Credit Card journal

Tags: gnucash

Gnucash seems to have lost hundreds of entries from my `Liabilities:Credit Card` account after importing transactions some months ago. The Credit Card journal shows no transactions after a certain date, but expense entries related to that account are clearly visible in their respective expense accounts.

When I try to Jump from the expense transaction to the Credit Card account, it goes to the bottom of the ledger with no corresponding entry.

These "ghost" entries show up as Funds Out when you attempt to reconcile, but the ledger for Credit Card is empty after a particular date. I found a [similar report from 2010](http://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-user/2010-March/034045.html) of missing entries after import.

I recovered an old database version from last year, and it already had the problem, so I've lost a lot of work. I am mostly worried that if I manually re-renter hundreds of transactions, that there will be duplicates but no way of seeing them. Tried running Check & Repair All - no changes.

Is there a way to force Gnucash to re-assert the entries in my Credit Card account based on the expense account entries?

Comment: Why the downvote? Is my question off-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there was an invisible filter set on my Credit Card account that was hiding entries outside of a particular date. So frustrating.

You can turn it off by right-clicking and choosing "Filter By..." and resetting to "Show All".